# Not getting the desired output in this code

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Occurrence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.next();
        int[] numberAmount = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            switch (input.charAt(i)) {
                case 0: 
                    numberAmount[0] += 1;
                    break;
                case 1: 
                    numberAmount[1] += 1;
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    numberAmount[2] += 1;
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    numberAmount[3] += 1;
                    break;
                case 4: 
                    numberAmount[4] += 1;
                    break;
                case 5: 
                    numberAmount[5] += 1;
                    break;
                case 6: 
                    numberAmount[6] += 1;
                    break;
                case 7: 
                    numberAmount[7] += 1;
                    break;
                case 8: 
                    numberAmount[8] += 1;
                    break;
                case 9: 
                    numberAmount[9] += 1;
                    break;
            }
            } 
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d: %d\n", i, numberAmount[i]);
        }


    }

}
```

We were given a task where we have to see how often a number occurs in a larger number.

Example 1:
011011011120203
Output:
0: 5
1: 7
2: 2
3: 1
4: 0
5: 0
6: 0
7: 0
8: 0
9: 0

When I run my code and input a number, the value for all the numbers is 0. What did I do wrong? I'm new to switch statements so sorry if the solution is obvious

Comment: What's the purpose of your code? Are you trying to count how many equal digits appears in each number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way to achieve is as below:

```
switch (input.charAt(i)) {
            case '0': 
                numberAmount[0] += 1;
                break;
            case '1': 
                numberAmount[1] += 1;
                break;
            case '2': 
                numberAmount[2] += 1;
                break;
            case '3': 
                numberAmount[3] += 1;
                break;
```

Make all the case values as `char` by enclosing them in single quote.

Comment: Thank you! This also works and looks more readable if someone else viewed my code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is happening because, `'1'` is not equal to `1`.

`1` is an integer

`'1'` is a character and corresponding int value is `48`.

So, the easiest that can be done in your code is

```
switch ((int)input.charAt(i) - 48) {
```

**Assumption**

INPUT String is made up of numeric values.

Comment: OP can also get rid of `switch` right ? just this line instead of all `switch/case` block `numberAmount[(int)input.charAt(i) - 48] += 1;`

Comment: Thank you! I converted 0, 1, 2 etc to 48, 49, 50 etc and it works perfect now.

Comment: @Yazan. Yeah. You are right. I was thinking to make minimal changes in code written by OP.

Answer (score 1):

As @niyasc said in the other answer, the implicit integer value of a character is not the value of the displayed digit.

You may use `Character.getNumericValue` to obtain the value you want.

```
switch (Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(i)))
```

To ensure that all characters are digits, you may want to use [Character.isDigit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)) just before your `switch` statement :

```
if(Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))){

    // do stuff
    // switch....


}
else{

   // warn user / ask for new input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the switch case what you are getting is a string . Please type cast it to a number and then run your program . It will work

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have given the hits to change `char` to `int`, but actually you don't need use `switch-case`, try the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scan.next();
    int[] numberAmount = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        numberAmount[(int)input.charAt(i) - 48] ++; // This is enough
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d: %d\n", i, numberAmount[i]);
    }
}
```